Why does GTK4 say "gtk_window_present: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed" when opening a dialog twice?
I am currently getting into developing GUIs with Python, GTK4 and libadwaita.
So far, my experience has been quite nice, but now I am hitting a problem:
When I create a AdwDialog, I can open it once, but if I close it and try to reopen it I get the following Error message:
(python3:45276): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:46:38.651: gtk_window_present: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

Here's a minimal reproducible example for this behavior:
import gi                                                                                                                                                                           
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')                                                                                                                                                    
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                    
from gi.repository import Gtk, Adw                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                    
class DemoWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):                                                                                                                                            
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                   
        super().__init__(**kwargs)                                                                                                                                                  
        self.set_title("Dialog Example")                                                                                                                                            
        self.set_default_size(200, 100)                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.dialog = Adw.Dialog(title="Dialog Example", parent=self)                                                                                                               
        self.closebtn = Gtk.Button(label="Close")                                                                                                                                   
        self.closebtn.connect("clicked", self.on_close_clicked)                                                                                                                     
        self.dialog.set_child(self.closebtn)                                                                                                                                        
        button = Gtk.Button(label="Open Dialog")                                                                                                                                    
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)                                                                                                                           
        self.set_child(button)                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def on_button_clicked(self, button):                                                                                                                                            
        self.dialog.present(self.get_root())                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def on_close_clicked(self, button):                                                                                                                                             
        self.dialog.close()                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                    
class DemoApp(Adw.Application):                                                                                                                                                     
    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                             
        super().__init__(application_id="org.example.demoapp")                                                                                                                      
        self.connect("activate", self.on_activate)                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def on_activate(self, app):                                                                                                                                                     
        self.win = DemoWindow(application=app)                                                                                                                                      
        self.win.present()                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                    
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                          
    DemoApp().run()

What am I doing wrong? Greatly appreciate your help
- Jens

Do not close dialog, hide it instead. The close method is equivalent of clicking system "close" button of the window. You can catch it, of course, and do some work (or even prevent from closing), but default action for "close" is "hide and destroy".
Alternatively, you can move dialog creation code into your on_button_clicked, right before presenting the dialog. This way it would be recreated every time, but wont keep memory, as when you create it during initialization of a parent window and kept until that window is destroyed.
